# Running code before initrd has been removed and after the root filesystem has been mounted

Tags: init-script, init, initrd

I looked here [Kernel boot process](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-process.html) and I tried to understand how to run a script before `initrd` filesystem removed and but after the root filesystem has been mounted (EncFS), If I understand it correctly, `/sbin/init` is executed after `initrd` filesystem is removed so if I'll put a script in `/etc/rc.d/` it won't have access to the `initrd` filesystem, I'm looking for solution to solve this problem.

Thanks.

BTW, the documentation [kernel initrd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt) mentions that `/sbin/init` is launched before `initrd` filesystem is freed, so It is possible to add scripts to `/etc/rc.d/` and they will run before `initrd` is freed?

Comment: That depends on how the initrd is organized. How is your initrd organized? Is it the one from some distribution? Are you sure it's an initrd and not an initramfs (most distributions have switched, even if the file is still called `initrd`)?

Answer (score 1):

(Only tested on debian/ubuntu based systems, don't know about suse/redhat etc.)

The best way is to add a file in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts` - `init-bottom` or `local-bottom` are the right directories in your case. Don't forget to make a `update-initramfs -c -k all` afterwards.